# Starting Alexa Skill in a specific state

Tags: javascript, node.js, alexa-skills-kit

Earlier I ran into the issue of Alexa not changing the state back to the blank state, and [found out that there is a bug in doing that](https://acloud.guru/forums/aws-advanced-alexa-skills-kit-free/discussion/-KdVHtsh_86AyhGlggiy/getting_back_to_blank_state). To avoid this issue altogether, I decided that I wanted to force my skill to always begin with `START_MODE`.

I used [this](https://github.com/bespoken/streamer/blob/master/lib/index.js) as my reference, where they set the state of the skill by doing `alexa.state = constants.states.START` before `alexa.execute()` at Line 55. However, when I do the same in my code, it does not work.

Below is what my skill currently looks like:

```
exports.newSessionHandler = {

    LaunchRequest () {
        this.hander.state = states.START;
        // Do something
    }

};

exports.stateHandler = Alexa.CreateStateHandler(states.START, {

    LaunchRequest () {
        this.emit("LaunchRequest");
    },

    IntentA () {
        // Do something
    },

    Unhandled () {
        // Do something
    }

});
```

I'm using `Bespoken-tools` to test this skill with `Mocha`, and when I directly feed `IntentA` like so:

```
alexa.intended("IntentA", {}, function (err, p)  { /*...*/ })
```

The test complains, `Error: No 'Unhandled' function defined for event: Unhandled`. From what I gather, this can only mean that the skill, at launch, is in the blank state (because I have not defined any `Unhandled` for that state), which must mean that `alexa.state` isn't really a thing. But then that makes me wonder how they made it work in the example code above.

I guess a workaround to this would be to create an alias for *every* intent that I expect to have in the `START_MODE`, by doing:

```
IntentA () {
    this.handler.state = states.START;
    this.emitWithState("IntentA");
}
```

But I want to know if there is a way to force my skill to start in a specific state because that looks like a much, much better solution in my eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you get a LaunchRequest, there is no state, as you discovered. If you look at the official Alexa examples, you will see that they solve this by doing what you said, making an 'alias' intent for all of their intents and just using them to change the state and then call themselves using 'emitWithState'.

This is likely the best way to handle it, as it gives you the most control over what state and intent is called.

Another option, assuming you want EVERY new session to start with the same state, is to leverage the 'NewSession' event. this event is triggered before a launch request, and all new sessions are funneled through it. your code will look somewhat like this:

```
NewSession () {
    if(this.event.request.type === Events.LAUNCH_REQUEST) {
        this.emit('LaunchRequest');
    } else if (this.event.request.type === "IntentRequest") {
        this.handler.state = states.START;
        this.emitWithState(this.event.request.intent.name);
    }
};
```

A full example of this can be seen here (check out the Handlers.js file): https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-node-device-address-api/tree/master/src

I would also recommend reading through this section on the Alexa GitHub: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#making-skill-state-management-simpler

**EDIT:**
I took a second look at the reference you provided, and it looks like they are setting the state outside of an alexa handler. So, assuming you wanted to mimic what they are doing, you would not set the state in your Intent handler, but rather the Lambda handler itself (where you create the alexa object).

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.appId = appId;
    alexa.registerHandlers(
        handlers,
        stateHandlers,
    );
    alexa.state = START_MODE;
    alexa.execute();
};
```

Comment: Do intent requests go through the `LaunchRequest` before it is called? Because even when I make an `IntentRequest` from the beginning (e.g. "Alexa, tell MyApp I said hi" instead of "Alexa, open MyApp"), it is still not found in the state that I want the skill to start in.

Comment: No, so a LaunchRequest is only triggered when someone invokes your skill without an intent ( "Alexa, launch MyApp" ). Anything else will attempt to invoke the intent that the user asked for ( Assuming 'I said hi' is mapped to IntentA, "Alexa, tell MyApp I said hi" will try and invoke 'IntentA' in the current state.).

Comment: OK, that's what I thought (: So I just saw your edit, and that didn't work for me (hence the question).. setting the state inside `index.handler` seems to not correctly adjust the "starting state" of Alexa. I have confirmed this by defining `Unhandled` & not defining `IntentA` in the blank state.

Comment: Oh ok, I suppose that would make sense why you asked :) Did you try setting the state through the NewSession event? All events (intent requests/launch request/etc.) go through this first when a new session happens (basically, whenever the skill is opened).

Comment: mmhm, so right now my skill does work, but that involves having a `NewSession` event exactly like you suggested in your answer! Thank you for that, by the way - but I just thought if I can get `alexa.state = START_MODE` to work it'd be a neat solution haha